# Cant connect from Node Js (in host) to a MySql container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I'm pretty new in Node and i was trying some examples from a book.

When i try to connect from NodeJS to a Mysql container i get this error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.1'
```

The MySql database is inside a Docker container created using this command:

```
> docker run --detach --name=test-mysql -p 3306:3306 
--env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root" mysql
```

This is the code from my Node program

```
'use strict';
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root'
});
connection.query(
    'SELECT "foo" AS first_field, "bar" AS second_field',
    function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(results);
        }
        connection.end();
    }
);
```

And i can connect to mysql from the shell using

```
>mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p
```

Also i can use -h 172.17.0.2 and -h 172.17.0.1

If i check my user@host inside Mysql

```
mysql> select user();
+-----------------+
| user()          |
+-----------------+
| root@172.17.0.1 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show grants for root;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So somehow, node is having trouble connecting to MySql but everything seems to be ok...

Thanks!!

NOTE: Solved!! Upgrading the package version of the mysql module fixed the problem. The previous version was "~2.0.0"

My package.json:

```
{
    "devDependencies":  {
        "jasmine-node": "",
        "mysql": "~2.1.x"
    }
}
```

Comment: try with the database name

Comment: I have tried with the db name and i still get the same error :(

Comment: then I think that the problem is in the Privileges

Comment: Solved!! The problem was in the mysql module version!